# ZBAR sdk not detecting QRCODES on iPhone 4s (ios 5.1)...?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios5.1, zbar-sdk

I have integrated the ZBAR sdk in my project and it is working fine for barcodes but it is not detecting the QRCodes. I am using the iPhone 4s and I don't have  any other device.. is this a known issue..? I am using the ZBarReaderViewController...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Double check that the scanner is configure for reading QR codes. Check my example below:

```
ZBarImageScanner *scanner = reader.scanner;

[scanner setSymbology:ZBAR_QRCODE
               config:ZBAR_CFG_ENABLE
                   to:1];
```

Comment: It looks like to me that the docs for zbar have this wrong: http://zbar.sourceforge.net/iphone/sdkdoc/camera.html part 3- configure the reader has the ZBAR_QR_CODE set to 0!

Answer (score 0):

This may be because of the data that you are encoding in QRCode. In Barcode it will be a number always, but in QR code code it is not like that. Try to store the data in a string and log the string.

Comment: your answer doesn't even make sense... :/

Answer (score 0):

i have use zbar Api for the UPC barcode scanning and its working very fine follow the below tutorial in ios 5 .please refer it and try it i have tested in devices its working well .

http://iphonenativeapp.blogspot.in/2011/07/qr-code-readerscanner-for-iphone-app-in.html

Thanks